# Does tbb::enumerable_thread_specific work in other thread libraries?

Tags: c++, tbb, thread-local-storage

`tbb::enumerable_thread_specific` gives thread-local storage when it is used in tbb parallel blocks. For example,

```
tbb::enumerable_thread_specific<int> tls(0);
tbb::parallel_for(0, n, [&] (int i) {
  tls.local() += i;
});
std::accumulate(tls.begin(), tls.end(), 0);
```

In the lambda function, tls.local() will not be used by other threads at the exact same time. When we accumulate the values in `tls`, it should give the sum of integers from 0 to (n-1). Will this property be hold when it is used in the other thread library, such as openmp, pthread? For example,

```
tbb::enumerable_thread_specific<int> tls(0);
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  tls.local() += i;
}
std::accumulate(tls.begin(), tls.end(), 0);
```

Will the above code lead to an unpredictable result?

Answer (score 1):

The `tbb::enumerable_thread_specific` should work with non-TBB threads as well. Please see how its local storage is managed from [relevant source lines](https://github.com/intel/tbb/blob/a803f276186fa2c286a357207832112265b448e4/include/tbb/enumerable_thread_specific.h#L280). We can see there is no TBB specificity around this, but common to OS API is used instead.

Comment: It is good to know how its local storage is managed using OS APIs. However, I think it is more than that. In TBB, if a parallel_for iteration or a task is executed it will not be interrupted unless there is another parallel_for (or similar thing) happens inside the iteration. This guarantees that during one iteration tls.local() will not be used by any other iteration until it ends. See 'https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/684814'. However, if other thread libraries are used, they cannot guarantee that. Then tbb::enumerable_thread_specific may not work properly.